# Getting MIDI in from USB MIDI keybord, cocoa mac

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, midi

i have this project where i have a USB MIDI keyboard that i need to comunicate with cocoa.
What framework makes this possible to get midi? Can't find any tutorials, is this even possible?

The keyboard is Worlde KS49B 49Key MIDI Controller

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you looked into CoreMIDI?

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/CACoreMIDIRef/_index.html

The same exists on Mac as well.

If you want to intercept the USB packets, then look at the `/Developer/Utilities/USB Prober.app` to see the low-level format; but I think you'd probably want to aim higher.

Answer (score 4):

I think you're looking for the Core MIDI framework. The [Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/CACoreMIDIRef/) has more information.